# Proving that the MLE remains invariant under measurable functions

Tags: statistics

I'm working through my course notes for Mathematical Statistics and I've come across an example which uses this without proving it (in fact without even explicitly specifying it). If $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE for $\theta$ and $g$ a measurable function, why is $\hat{g(\theta)}$ MLE of $g({\theta})$.

Comment: In addition to @J.G.'s answer below, which is essentially Zehna's proof, have a look at [Olive (2004)](http://parker.ad.siu.edu/Olive/simle.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Write $\eta:=g(\theta)$. Suppose the likelihood on some dataset is $L(\theta)=L^\ast(\eta)$, where our notation hides dependence on any other parameters. Let $\hat{\theta},\,\hat{\eta}$ be respective MLEs of $\theta,\,\eta$ so$$L^\ast(\hat{\eta})=\sup_\eta\sup_{\{\theta|g(\theta)=\eta\}}L(\theta)=\sup_\theta L(\theta)=L(\hat{\theta})=\sup_{\{\theta|g(\theta)=g(\hat{\theta})\}}L(\theta)=L^\ast(g(\hat{\theta})).$$This is theorem 7.2.10 in Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*.